# Program calculates increasing numbers

Tags: python

A hiker is going on a walkabout and plans to hike for 10 days. Enter in the number of miles walked each day. The procedure should return the length of the longest stretch of days in which the hiker walk more miles than the day before.

Please enter the number of miles hiked on each of the ten days:
5
7
4
3
7
6
8
11
3
9

There were 3 days in a row in which the hiker’s distance increased every day. The hiker walked 25 miles during that stretch.

this is what the program should look like. 
This is what code I have so far

```
def hikertrip():
    print("Please enter the number of miles hiked on each of the ten days:")
    day1= eval(input())
    day2= eval(input())
    day3= eval(input())
    day4= eval(input())
    day5= eval(input())
    day6= eval(input())
    day7= eval(input())
    day8= eval(input())
    day9= eval(input())
    day10= eval(input())
    totaldays= day1 + day2 + day3 + day4 + day5 + day6 + day7 + day8 + day9 + day10
    TotalDistSoFar= 0
    TotalDaysSoFar= 0
    MaxDistance= 0
    MaxDays= 10
    print(" There were", TotalDaysSoFar " days in a row in which the hiker's distance increased")
    print(" every day. The hiker walked ", TotalDistSoFar, " miles during that stretch")
hikertrip()
```

I know I need to tell the program to calculate stretch of days by creating a loop that resets the TotalDaysSoFar when the number is less than the next number. I am bad at putting my words into code so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try using arrays insteads and then iterating over it. http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/python/3942-arrays-in-python.html

Comment: It sure is nice of your program to give malicious users ten whole tries to wreck things with `eval(input())`. ;)

Comment: @iCodez: I'm guessing the teacher told them to use that. In fact, how much do you want to bet the teacher only knows Python 2.7, and Python isn't his preferred language anyway, but he was told to teach 3.4, and saw somewhere that `eval(input())` is the 3.x equivalent of 2.x's `input()`?

Comment: @abarnert - Simple test to judge the quality of your Python teacher: ask them what `eval` is used for.  An unqualified one will respond with something like "Oh, you can use that for..." where as a real one will immediately say "Who told you about that?!" :)